# Lebesgue measure and integration in probability theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In the literature, "Lebesgue Integration" sometimes refers to Lebesgue's general technique of integrating relative to a measure, and sometimes to the specific case where we use the particular Lebesgue measure (or Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure) on a Euclidean space.

My questions is: in probability text-books and papers, when notions like expected value in continuous cases is defined in terms of Lebesgue integration of the probability density function, is it assumed that we are using not just Lebesgue integration, but the Lebesgue measure? I.e. that, in effect, this particular measure is standardly assumed to be the measure that is used in the definition of these terms?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a probability density function is a density with respect to Lebesgue measure.
However,  more advanced probability texts consider arbitrary probability measures, and there one uses the general notion of integration with respect to a measure.